# Need some help understanding the usefulness and point of promises

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, axios

I want to start using axios to get data from a restful api I have already coded, but I keep on recieving [object Promise] instead of something useful like data.

Here is my code.

```
import axios from "axios";

const get = url => {
  return axios
    .get(url)
    .then(response => {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return error;
    });
};
```

I console.log the return value of this and get [object Promise]. I need the data my restful api is sending back when I call get in the code below.

```
const {get, post} = client;

const data = get("localhost:4000/data");

console.log(`Data: ${data}`);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to wait for the promise by calling `then()`.  Learn the basics of promises; you cannot escape from async.

Comment: The *point* of a promise is to use asynchronous actions in a synchronous way. Check out `async await` for a neater way to use promises.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Here is the thing I am not coding something that returns a promise. I have obtained a promise from the code above. I just need to extract something that resembles data. Your link has no relevance here.

Comment: The point of promises is that [they are returnable objects still acting like asynchronous callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572), to help dealing with asynchronous tasks. But no, it is still fundamentally impossible to extract a value from the promise, as it fulfills in the future only.

Answer (score -1):

Your `get()` returns another promise. In order get data or log it you need to chain it again `get().then(console.log);`.

Comment: could get().then(data => return data); work?

Comment: Yes, but it would again return a promise. As @SLaks said: You cannot escape from async.

Comment: You literally just said get().then is the answer and then tell me no it is not the answer because I didn't use async. Can you show me a working example of getting the data from an axios get request?

Comment: What you have asked is valid syntax. You cannot return from an async function in an asymc scope. Two options: 1. Make the scope async and use await , e.g. `async () => { const data = await get('url'); console.log(data); };` or 2. Put all the logic for handling `data` into the `then()` block e.g. `get().then(data => { console.log(data); // ALL logic around data goes in here });`.

Comment: I understand now. It just seems like it doesn't really get you out of callback hell when the final .then() requires a callback or some form of logic or function.